# using two queries to get 'data1' OR 'data2' in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from firebase only if the user is not saved in the document. Because I need a or-query, which is not possible in Firebase, I decided to use RxDart's CombinedStreams with two steams:

```
var streamOne = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('jobs')
  .where('jobState', isEqualTo: 1)
  .where('userOne', isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .snapshots();
var streamTwo = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('jobs')
  .where('jobState', isEqualTo: 1)
  .where('userTwo', isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .snapshots();
```

But my app shows the data even if the current user is in 'userOne' OR 'userTwo'. Is it possible to avoid this and get the data just if the currentUser is not 'userOne' OR 'userTwo'?

Comment: Is it working when only using streamOne?

Comment: yeah, while using just one query the method works; but I want to filter the array both ways

Comment: you only want to get the documents from firestore for which both userOne and userTwo is not currentUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed: if the UID is in `userOne`, the second query will still return that document, and vice versa. What you want is actually an **AND**: the documents where the UID is not in `userOne` *and* not in `userTwo`.

Unfortunately though that query also isn't possible on Firestore, as [all `not-equal` conditions in a query must be on the same field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations).

There is no way to capture your logic in a single query, and you will have to filter the documents fo `userOne` and `userTwo` in your application code instead.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a good example online? I have no idea how to start... My only idea is to get the data with the streamOne query (above, where I filter 'userOne') in an array and than filter the data again in that array with 'userTwo'

Comment: It seems fairly straightforward to me: get all the docs from the collection, then loop over the snapshot list and filter the ones that don't have the UID of the current user in either of the fields (something like `doc.data()['userOne'] != uid && doc.data()['userTwo'] != uid`).